# CTRL+Pageup and CTRL-Pagedown suddenly stopped working

Tags: debian, cinnamon

I am running Debian with Cinnamon and I use CTRL-Pageup/Pagedown all the time for nearly all apps that I use. I restarted my computer last week and it just suddenly stopped working. It doesn't work anymore for any apps (Terminal, Firefox, Chrome, etc.). The buttons still work, I can still use Pageup/Pageup to jump down or up or and the CTRL button still works. I looked into the settings and I don't see a command for this but it has worked for weeks and now all of a sudden it doesn't work. I tried to make a custom shortcut for it but it is asking for a file and I'm not sure what to do there.

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you found anything on that in meantime? Also on my Mint have been working for ages and now they are not doing anything.

Comment: I believe the problem is that I have multiple desktops and that usually leads to problems. I have cinnamon and kde plasma and the kde plasma settings are also showing under the cinnamon desktop. I'm just going to back everything up and do a fresh install with only one desktop.

Comment: I had cinnamon and mate installed in mint. Removed mate to keep only cinnamon but still the problem is there. I would say that this problem started back in august 2020 for me. There was an update that messed the behavior.

Comment: I figured it out. It was due to the Redshift panel widget. When I removed the widget it started working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with an applet called "QRedshift". It had used the shortcuts CTRL+PGUP/PGDN. If anyone is having this issue I recommend checking any applets being used in the panel and checking in their settings if they have any shortcuts being used.